# Do Beacons Deliver Content?

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, google-beacon-platform

Using the RadiusNetworks [Proximity Kit](https://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com), I have created a kit. Within the kit, I have created a region and registered my dev beacon. Next, I have attached key/value attributes to the beacon. My question is, once synched are these attributes physically stored on the beacon?

[This](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/01/10/ibeacon-misconceptions.html) article confuses me.  Per this article:

> They don't deliver anything. They simply broadcast a few identifiers.
>   Beacons broadcast a UUID, Major Value, and Minor Value. No user
>   consumable content is broadcast, just these IDs.

Along with the other info (UUID, major and minor versions), don’t these beacons also broadcast the key/value pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iBeacons can only transmit one type of data: the UUID number. Beacons using the new Eddystone standard can transmit three types of data: UID (similar to UUID), URL (website addresses) and TLM (telemetry, such as temperature and beacon battery level). Standard beacons don't have any memory to store arbitrary data, but you could work around that by using the Lightblue Bean or building a custom beacon from Raspberry Pi.  Like already mentioned, another option would be to use a backend, where you store and retrieve the data. We did a museum application that functioned with iBeacons using our Proximi.io platform, which is able to store the data for temporary offline mode, and re-syncs, when Internet access becomes available again. A third option would be to just build in all the data into the application.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Proximity Kit Documentation](https://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com/docs/overview), step 2 of the lifecycle says that your app will sync with their back end and that your "region data and configuration is cached and can be updated in the background."

I believe that your key/value pairs are stored in the cloud (and synced to your mobile device), and not stored on the beacon (since there is no way for their back end to connect to a beacon).

Comment: I was hoping for the first sync, Proximity Kit SDK (bundled as a AAR) downloads and caches data on phone but then the SDK writes to the internal memory of the beacon. But, it seems that's not the case here...beacons provide no internal storage...all they broadcast is UUID, major and minor version.

Comment: Their doc does not state that the app updates the beacon (which sounds pretty insecure). They only state that data is synced to the mobile device. It should not matter to the end user, anyway, as long as they have the right app.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Per my understanding
Step 1- developer registers a beacon in the Proximity dashboard and adds key/value pairs as meta-data info to a beacon

Step 2- developer creates an Android app and the app uses the Android SDK

Step 3- the proximity SDK maintains a cache (it pulls beacon UUID,version and metadata from back-end)

Step 4- once a beacon is started, it broadcasts it's UUID, versions,  proximity kit picks up the event and calls lifecycle methods 

Step 5 - the proximity sdk, now compares the UUID, versions with the info in its cache and returns values...

Comment: Thanks. Keeping radiousnetworks aside, are there beacons  from other OEMs that provide a feature/mechanism to store arbitrary data as key/value pairs on their internal storage which can be easily configured? How do personal beacons work? For example, a beacon attached to a painting in a museum.  When a visitor walks up to the painting, in addition to its UUID, versions (major and minor) can the beacon also transmit other useful contextual info?